# Simple sql server and datagrid questions

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

i have tables driver, cars and trailers they are all in relationship. and main table named Transportation with relationship driver. i use inner join to show transportation on my datagrid there are columns : LoadName, transportationStart, End, DateTime, DriverName, carSerialNumber, trailerSN and so on... its shows everything good but when i change CarID in Drivers table grid shows realtime info. how can i make that grid shows that information when this row added?
Does is essential to make new columns in Transportation table where i will write serialNumbs of trailers and cars?
Thanks

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  Are you asking how to refresh the datagrid, insert a row, or add a column to a table?  Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: Sorry. its my English fault. For example on 1 semptember car tt-3000 was connected with trailer kk-6000. now is 1 octomber and tt-3000 is connected another trailer pp-4000. my grid will show that transportation(which was in 1 sempt) 5 was made buy car tt-3000 with pp-4000. sorry i cant do more clearly . i want show that on 1sempt transportation was made buy tt-3000

Comment: @user508284: That's not a problem, we can still help I'm just trying to figure out which problem you want to solve.

Comment: i edited. i hope that will be more understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebind the datagrid by reloading your data and it will show the new row once it has been added.